# Gather mouse position on canvas using Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

Is there a simple way to gather the mouse pointer on the screen without using jquery to rotate something. I have a figure on screen with arms and want them to rotate in the direction of the muse pointer. For Example how would I do something like shown below

```
if (mosue_moved_up) {
digit = 1;
} else if (mouse_moved_down) {
digit = 2;
} else if (mouse_moved_right) {
digit =3;
} else if (mouse_moved_left) {
digit = 4;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting the mouse movement relative to the last mouse position or relative to a fixed position on the canvas? Also, what do you want if the mouse moves both right & up at the same time?

Comment: @markE if the mouse moved up and right at same time arm would rotate anti-clockwise, not sure what you mean by relative to a fixed position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can get the angle between mouse and shoulder like this:**

```
var dx = mouseX - shoulderX;
var dy = mouseY - shoulderY;
var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
```

**And you can get the arms endpoint from the shoulder towards the mouse like this:**

```
var endX = shoulderX + armlength * Math.cos(angle);
var endY = shoulderY + armlength * Math.sin(angle);
```

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var offsetX=BB.left;
var offsetY=BB.top;
ctx.lineCap='round';
ctx.fillStyle='blue';
ctx.strokeStyle='green';
ctx.lineWidth=8;

var PI=Math.PI;
var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var armlength=65;

canvas.onmousemove=handleMousemove;

draw(0,0);

function handleMousemove(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var mouseX=e.clientX-offsetX;
  var mouseY=e.clientY-offsetY;
  draw(mouseX,mouseY);
}

function draw(mouseX,mouseY){
  var dx=mouseX-cx;
  var dy=mouseY-cy;
  var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
  var x=cx+armlength*Math.cos(angle);
  var y=cy+armlength*Math.sin(angle);

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

  ctx.fillRect(cx-15,cy-10,30,100);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(cx,cy);
  ctx.lineTo(x,y);
  ctx.strokeStyle='green';
  ctx.stroke();

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>"Arm" will move as the mouse moves.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```